# "All posts" incorrect displayed on graph on analytics page

Tags: bug, status-completed, graphs, site-analytics

I have access only to SOru analytics (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/site-analytics), so can provide gif only from here.

> [image]

Все сообщения = all posts.
Вопросы = questions.
Ответы = answers.

I guess it should be: `All posts = answers + questions`. But right now `All posts == questions`.

Exported CSV also has incorrect values.

Comment: Same on other sites. Good catch!

Comment: @Shog9 tnx for fix (: